# How to give one sample text input to a pre-trained LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I am trying to do toxic comment classification. I found a dataset in https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge. It has many comments with corresponding values for label class "toxic", "severe_toxic" ..etc. I want to classify my single text input to the corresponding labeled class.
I have created and trained a model using LSTM. Now I want to give a single text sentence as input to the model to predict the output.
But I don't know how to convert the text input and give it to the trained model.

The source-code has been obtained from [kaggle challange](https://www.kaggle.com/sbongo/for-beginners-tackling-toxic-using-keras).

[summary of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6WoX.png)

Comment: Can you please tell how have you  trained the model?

Comment: On the test-set, you have to use the same method that you have used for processing inputs in the training-set.

Comment: I got the code from [link](https://www.kaggle.com/sbongo/for-beginners-tackling-toxic-using-keras) . Then I saved the model. Now I want to test the model with new text sentence. So how to convert the input text to feed the model. @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Comment: You can use:
`y_predict = model.predict(X_te, batch_size=batch_size)`

Comment: `y_predict` will have prediction output; You can then convert the one-hot of predictions to class labels.

Comment: Thankyou @AshwinGeetD'Sa for your valuable response. I`m a beginner in this area, so a lot to learn. You helped me a lot. !!

Comment: when I try to input like this, `y_pred = model.predict(X_t[0], batch_size=32)` I am getting an error **ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (200,) but got array with shape (1,)**

Comment: It is supposed to be `y_pred = model.predict(X_te, batch_size=32)` ; X_te is your test set

Comment: Okay I got that, but I just try to predict with a single input, how do I do that @AshwinGeetD'Sa. How do I reshape the input then,

Comment: y_pred = model.predict(X_te[0])

Comment: I did that but I got an error, that I have mentioned just above @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Comment: In that case, use `y_pred = model.predict(X_te[0].reshape(200,))`

Comment: Should I consider posting it as an answer if it was helpful?

Comment: yes, you can post it as an answer.. thank you for your time !! @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prediction can be done using `predict()` function as below:

`y_predict = model.predict(X_te, batch_size=batch_size)`
Where, `X_te` is the pre-processed test-set. The pre-processing is generally same for training-set and test-set.

In case, if you want to predict for a single instance from the test set, the input has to be reshaped, as given below:

`y_pred = model.predict(X_te[0].reshape(200,))`